# probability: nonlinear best predictor $\hat{Y} = g(X)$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Consider $X\sim\mathcal{U}(-1,1)$ and $Y = X^2$. The nonlinear predictor is defined as
$$
\hat{Y} = g(X) = E_{Y|X}[Y|x_i]
$$
Now $E_{Y|X}[Y|x_i] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y\frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_X(x)}dy$. How do I find $f_{X, Y}(x, y)$? 
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}(f_X(\sqrt{y}) + f_X(-\sqrt{y}))\\
&= \begin{cases}
1/\sqrt{y}, & 0<y<1\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Should it actually be $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$ instead?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ do not have a _joint_ density since knowledge of $X$ determines $Y$ completely. So, don't look at formulas but rather ask yourself; if I know that $X$ has value $0.2$ (say) what is the _best_ estimate that I can make of the value of $Y$? And if your answer is anything other than $(0.2)^2 = 0.04$, don't quit your day job as yet.

Comment: @DilipSarwate if they don't have a joint density, how would I determine $E_{Y|X}[Y|x_i]$ which I am asked to do?

Comment: There are two cases where E(Y|X) is very easy to compute: when Y is independent of X, and when Y is a function of X. Your question falls into one of these cases. This comment is merely rephrasing @DilipSarwate's one.

Comment: To define E(Y|X) first and foremost through densities is a terrible idea. Who is being cruel with you like that?

Comment: And there is no alternative *definition* later on in the book?

Comment: Funny, precisely the exercise asking to compute E(X^2|X) is a convincing argument that densities are not the key to conditional expectations since, *as @Dilip explained*, (X,X^2) has no density.

Comment: So, to be clear, you have no definition of E(Y|X) not relying on densities?

Comment: @Did there isn't one apparent in the book through page 400

Comment: Hmmm... Here what the book ought to explain: For every integrable Y, there exists a unique measurable function u such that (1) u(X) is integrable and (2) E(Yv(X))=E(u(X)v(X)) for every bounded measurable function v. This (almost surely unique) random variable u(X) is called u(X)=E(Y|X). If P(X=x)>0 for some x, then u(x)=E(Y|X=x)=E(Y;X=x)/P(X=x). If (X,Y) has a density f, then u(x)=∫yf(x,y)dy/∫f(x,z)dz. If (X,Y) is independent, then E(Y|X)=E(Y). If Y=w(X) then E(Y|X)=w(X). If Y=w(X)Z where (X,Z) is independent, then E(Y|X)=E(Z)w(X). And now, one can start to work...

Comment: Why did you delete your comment mentioning the book you are following with no proper definition of E(Y|X)?

Comment: @Did cleaning up comment thread

Comment: Most unfortunate to "clean" this piece of information. You might want to repost it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall x_i\in [-1,1]$   When given $X=x_i$ then $Y$ is certainly equal to $x_i^2$, so we have a probability mass with a support of one point:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P[Y=y\mid X=x_i] & = \begin{cases} 1 & : y=x_i^2 \\ 0 & : y\neq x_i^2\end{cases} 
\\[4ex]
\mathsf E_{Y\mid X}(Y\mid x_i) & = \sum_{y=x_i^2} y\, \mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=x_i)
\\ & = x_i^2 
\end{align}$$

---

**Remark**   It is usually considered that clearly: $\mathsf E[h(X)\mid X] = h(X)$ , so you needn't bother showing this work.

$$\mathsf E\left(X^2\,\middle|\, X=x_i\right) = x_i^2$$

Comment: What is the notation $E_{Y\mid X}(Y\mid x)$ supposed to mean? Is it $E(Y\mid X=x)$? Then why not use $E(Y\mid X=x)$ instead?

Comment: @Did It's the notation convention dustin used in the OP; presumably taken from his book.

Comment: And it is a horrible notation, mathematically speaking, hence why condone it?